# Ajax done not firing, unless breakpoint added

Tags: javascript

Very new to Javascript and Ajax. My code is below.  If I set a breakpoint at the .done and another within the body of the `.done` function, I hit both breakpoints. If I remove the breakpoint at .done, the body of the done does not execute? The function is called by a .click event.

```
var zipcode_entered = "false";
var zipcode_value;

function GetWeather() {
  var my_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipcode_value + ",us&appid=c8432c9f909e23e8a141942a1ffcec0e&units=imperial";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: my_url,
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(weatherResponse) {
    console.log(weatherResponse);
    $('#city').val(weatherResponse.name);
    $('#CurrentWeather').val(weatherResponse.weather.description);
    $('#temperature').val(parseInt(weatherResponse.main.temp));
    $('#humidity').val(parseInt(weatherResponse.main.humidity));
    $('#mintemp').val(parseInt(weatherResponse.main.temp_min));
    $('#maxtemp').val(parseInt(weatherResponse.main.temp_max));
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  //this code checks that the zipcode isn't blank and has 5 characters
  $("#zipcode").blur(function() {
    zipcode_value = $(this).val();
    if ((zipcode_value !== "") && (zipcode_value.length == 5)) {
      zipcode_entered = "true";
    } else {
      zipcode_entered = "false";
    }
  });

  $("#submit").click(function() {
    if (zipcode_entered == "true") {
      GetWeather();
    } else {
      $("#zipcode").val("Error");
    };

  });
});
```

Comment: Can you specify more about result?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should use booleans rather than strings for flags like `zipcode_entered`.

Comment: I suspect that an error is being thrown inside the `.done` handler, and there is no `.catch` handler to capture that. Add `.catch(error => console.error(error))` and then run it again to see if something is blowing up.